# Why am I getting "error: expected expression"?

Tags: c++

I am writing a program to do the following:

"print a set of real numbers in descending order (sorting). The program should also print out the median of the numbers input and how many numbers were input. The program should read in numbers until a negative number is read. The negative number serves as a sentinel or marker telling the program when to stop reading numbers. The program should then sort the numbers and print them out in order from largest to smallest. Note, the sentinel number is not to be considered as one of the numbers, it should not be printed. The program should be able to handle up to 100 input numbers. If the user attempts to enter more than 100 numbers, the program should print an error message and quit."

I know my syntax is incorrect as I am very new to C++. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int get_numbers(float nums[])
{
    float num;
    int i = 0;

    cout << "Enter a real number ";
    cin >> num;

    while (num >= 0)
    {
        if (i == 100)
        {
            cout << "Error: too many numbers read. Good bye";
            break;
        }

        nums[i] = num; 
        i += 1;

        cout << "Enter a real number: ";
        cin >> num;
    }
    return i;
}

int sort_numbers(float nums[], int num)
{
    int swapped, j, i, temp;

    swapped = true;
    for(i = 1; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (swapped != true)
        {
            break;
        }
        swapped = false;

        for(j = 1; i < (num-i); i++)
        {
            if (nums[j] < nums[j+1])
            {
                temp = nums[j];
                nums[j] = nums[j+1];
                nums[j+1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int print_numbers(float nums[], int num)
{
    int i, median;

    cout << "The numbers in descending order are: ";
    for(i = 1; i < num; i++)
    {
        cout << (nums[i]);
    }

    if (num % 2 == 0)
    {
        median = (nums[num/2-1] + nums[num/2]) / 2;
    }
    else
    {
        median = (nums[num/2]);
    }

    cout << "The median number is " << median;

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int num_numbers = 0;
    float a[] =[0.0] * 100;

    num_numbers = get_numbers(a);
    sort_numbers(a, num_numbers);
    print_numbers(a, num_numbers);

    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting an error that states "error: expected expression" on line 85 at the bottom for the line
`float a[] =[0.0] * 100;`

I don't know the syntax well enough to even know what to try to fix. Can you help me get my program running?

EDIT:
I am translating a Python program to C++. Here is the python program:

```
    i = 0

    num = float(input("Enter a real number: "))

    while num >= 0:
        if i == 100:
            print("Error: too many numbers read. Good bye")
            exit()

        nums[i] = num
        i += 1

        num = float(input("Enter a real number: "))

    return i

def sort_numbers(nums, num):

    swapped = True
    for i in range(1,num):
        if swapped != True:
            break
        swapped = False
        for j in range(num-i):
            if nums[j] < nums[j+1]:
                temp = nums[j]
                nums[j] = nums[j+1]
                nums[j+1] = temp
                swapped = True


def print_numbers(nums, num):

    print("The numbers in descending order are:")
    for i in range(num):
        print(nums[i])

    if num%2 == 0:
        median = (nums[num//2 - 1] + nums[num//2]) / 2
    else:
        median = nums[num//2]

    print("The median number is", median)

def main():
    num_numbers = 0
    a = [0.0] * 100

    num_numbers = get_numbers(a)
    sort_numbers(a, num_numbers)
    print_numbers(a, num_numbers)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What do you expect to accomplish with "float a[] =[0.0] * 100;"? What do you think it should mean?

Comment: Honestly I am not sure. I am translating a python program to C++.

Comment: I'm not passing judgement on any assignment. I'm sorry to hear that you have poorly-trained teachers, but nobody on stackoverflow.com can do anything about that, unfortunately. My point is if one attempts to translate a program from one language to the other, one needs to actually know what the existing program is supposed to be doing. If you can't explain what one particular line of code is supposed to do, how can you expect anyone to be able to help you to write what it's supposed to do?

Comment: declare a in main() like this `float a[100] ={0.0};`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the better version of your program, I have made a couple of changes.
You can open both your and this program in a diff viewer to locate all the changes.
I have also added a better version of `get_numbers` with name `get_numbers_` which you may use or discard, this function does not ask the user for 101st number and then complains why have you entered :)

Here are a few learning if you are interested:

- Do not repeat yourself as far as possible so avoid writing "Enter a real number" multiple times.
- There is no need to return 0 or anything from all functions if you are not going to use the return value
- If you are returning a value from a function then make use of it
- And some c++ syntax that you should learn

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int get_numbers_(float nums[])
{
    float num;
    int i = 0;

    while (i < 100)
    {
        cout << "Enter a real number: ";
        cin >> num;
        if(num < 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        nums[i] = num;
        i += 1;
    }

    return i;
}
int get_numbers(float nums[])
{
    float num;
    int i = 0;

    cout << "Enter a real number ";
    cin >> num;

    while (num >= 0)
    {
        if (i == 100)
        {
            cout << "Error: too many numbers read. Good bye";
            break; //use exit() because you are telling Good bye
        }

        nums[i] = num; 
        i += 1;

        cout << "Enter a real number: ";
        cin >> num;
    }
    return i;
}
void sort_numbers(float nums[], int num)
{
    int swapped, j, i;
    float temp;
    swapped = true;
    for(i = 1; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (swapped != true)
        {
            break;
        }
        swapped = false;

        for(j = 0; j < (num-i); j++)
        {
            if (nums[j] < nums[j+1])
            {
                temp = nums[j];
                nums[j] = nums[j+1];
                nums[j+1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

void print_numbers(float nums[], int num)
{
    int i;
    float median;

    cout << "The numbers in descending order are: ";
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        cout << nums[i] << " ";
    }

    if (num % 2 == 0)
    {
        median = (nums[num/2-1] + nums[num/2]) / 2;
    }
    else
    {
        median = nums[num/2];
    }

    cout << endl << "The median number is " << median << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int num_numbers = 0;
    float a[100] ={0.0};

    num_numbers = get_numbers(a);
    if(num_numbers > 0)
    {
        sort_numbers(a, num_numbers);
        print_numbers(a, num_numbers);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "No numbers entered" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```